# Cast interface{} to struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, casting, type-conversion

I have the following struct in one module:

```golang
type Event struct {
    Name    string      `json:"name"`
    Version string      `json:"version"`
    Payload interface{} `json:"payload"`
}
```

the goal is, that I can accept arbitrary structs as `Payload` and send the final structs of type `Event` as json-serialized strings using `json.Marshal` with some messaging-service.

However, when I try to `json.Unmarshal` in another project, I can't access the fields inside of `Event.Payload`, because Go obviously doesn't know about its final type.

I tried to use something like this:

```golang
type EventPayload struct{
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

// ...

event := &events.Event{}
event.Payload = &EventPayload{}

if err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, event); err != nil {
    return err
}

event.Payload.Name  // Won't work: "type interface{} has no field or method Status"
```

however, Go still thinks, that `event.Payload` is an `interface{}`.

How can I tell Go the correct struct-type in this case?

Comment: The value in `Event.Payload` will be of type `map[string]interface{}` for JSON objects, and `[]interface{}` for JSON arrays. You can't cast or type assert it to any other type. You can only type assert a `struct` from an `interface{}` value if it truly holds a value of that type. Type assertion does not convert the value nor does it magically create new values.

Comment: `Unmarshal` doesn't create a type based on the JSON. It unmarshal into the type you give it. Are you looking to unmarshal any payload on the receiving side? Why not `Unmarshal` into the right type directly?

Comment: @super wouldn't that mean, that I would have to duplicate the original code of the `Event`-struct, just with a different type for the `Payload`-field? My goal was to keep `Event` as generic as possible and reuse the code, that I've written previously.

Comment: And as a general comment: I didn't think, that this question was THAT bad! I'm sorry, if the question reveals my lack of understanding Go in general.

Comment: @TimHilt On the `Marshal` side it can be kept generic, but if you want the json converted into a proper type you would need to break that part of the code out and use a different struct for each type of `Payload`, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done so now.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly what you're describing, you just need to use a type assertion to get the underlying type back. `json.Unmarshal`, provided an `interface{}` field with a concrete type prepopulated, **will** use that concrete type.

```
event := &Event{}
event.Payload = &EventPayload{}
msg := []byte(`{"Name": "foo", "Version": "1", "Payload": {"Name": "bar"}}`)

if err := json.Unmarshal(msg, event); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

pl := event.Payload.(*EventPayload)
fmt.Println(pl.Name)
```

Working example (slightly modified to run in playground): https://play.golang.org/p/IDXLKeMGw8_1

Comment: Oh, so I was just missing the type assertion at the end! That's interesting and very important insight for me. Thank you very much. I can confirm, that it works in my application. :)

Comment: Just out of interest; why do I get so many downvotes on this particular question? I didn't think, that it was a bad one in the first place and now, that I know that I was so close, I understand the downvotes even less. Is this maybe bad practice or wrong use of Go?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I tell Go the correct struct-type in this case?

You cannot. This is not how encoding/json.Unmarshal works. You either have to unmarshal into a proper type or something else or use json.Raw message and do a second unmarshaling or whatnot but they way you approached it simply doesn't work.